# Single query approach to split and copy string values in a column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, substring

This is a part of my [previous question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/93123/how-to-speed-up-a-multiple-select-query).

I have the below logic to split a string value from a column in table `tblProjects` as below:

```
SELECT  @Docs = Documents FROM tblProjects WHERE ID = @ID 
SET @Docs = @Docs + '$'
SET @pos = 0
SET @len = 0

WHILE CHARINDEX('$', @Docs, @pos + 1)>0
BEGIN
  SET @len = CHARINDEX('$', @Docs, @pos + 1) - @pos
  SET @value = SUBSTRING(@Docs, @pos, @len)

  IF CHARINDEX('|', @value) >0
  BEGIN
    SELECT  @type = SUBSTRING(@value, 1, CHARINDEX('|', @value) - 1),
            @name = SUBSTRING(@value, CHARINDEX('|', @value) + 1, 200)
    INSERT INTO tblDocuments VALUES(@ID, @value, @type, @name)
  END   

  SET @pos = CHARINDEX('$', @Docs, @pos + @len) +1
END
```

A sample input would be

```
insert into tblProjects(ID, Documents) 
values('P_1', 'gdgfg|jkkgk$bkgkkj|kjgkgk$vjffj|Khkgjhg$jkgkvghv|kbkghhkgk');
```

I need to split the `Documents` string and insert the values into a separate table. Values delimited by `|` should go into separate columns of the same row, whereas values for a particular row are delimited by `$`.

Is there a single query method to complete this operation, for all rows in the table, in the minimum possible time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should make use of a split string function.

```
select left(S.Item, charindex('|', S.Item) - 1),
       stuff(S.Item, 1, charindex('|', S.Item), '')
from dbo.tblProjects as P
  cross apply dbo.SplitString(P.Documents, '$') as S;
```

Aaron Bertrand blogged about some of the alternatives you have in [Split strings the right way – or the next best way](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings)

Answer (score -1):

The following example works perfectly fine with this single query -

Here is the data example

> Table = **CityItem**

```
ID     Name     City       Items
===    ===      =====      ======
1      Michael  Miami      item|item2|item3|item4|item5
2      Jorge    Hallandale item|item2|item3|item4|item5
```

**SQL Query** for the result given below -

```
SELECT ID, Name, City, s.value AS Item
FROM CityItem as mb
  CROSS APPLY dbo.ufn_N_Split('|', mb.Items) as s;
```

NOTE:- "ufn_N_Split" is a custom function that splits string values (like items) into a column named "value".

**Output / Result** -

```
ID     Name     City       Item
===    =====    =====      =======
1      Michael  Miami      item
1      Michael  Miami      item2
1      Michael  Miami      item3
1      Michael  Miami      item4
1      Michael  Miami      item5
2      Jorge    Hallandale item
2      Jorge    Hallandale item2
2      Jorge    Hallandale item3
2      Jorge    Hallandale item4
2      Jorge    Hallandale item5
...
...
...
```

Comment: I dont see the function `ufn_N_Split` definition !